# Result of program using pdfbox built with maven-shade-plugin is different than normal NetBeans Run

Tags: java, maven, pdfbox, maven-shade-plugin

I have program in java which uses PDFBox 1.7.1 and it is build with maven-shade-plugin 2.0.

Here is the code which uses PDFBox api:

```
public class PdfFile {

    protected PDDocument document = null;

    public boolean load(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(is);
        parser.parse();
        COSDocument cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
        this.document = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
        return true;
    }

    public byte[] extractText() throws IOException {
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        byte[] text = pdfStripper.getText(this.document).getBytes();

        return text;
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        if(this.document != null) {
            this.document.close();
        }
    }
}
```

So basicly method `load()` loads pdf document from byte array and method `extractText()` returns text extracted from PDF as a byte array. It works when I run program from NetBeans `Run` button, but when I run it from single jar built with maven-shade-plugin the returned text is in wrong character encoding. For example word:

```
odpowiadająca (normal polish characters)
odpowiadajšca (netbeans run)
odpowiadajÄca (single shade jar)
```

I know it's exactly same file (byte array) which comes as argument `to PdfFile.load()` on both runs. So the problem is with PDF box returning text in two different formats...

I have 3 questions:

1. Why in jar built with shade plugin encoding is different?
2. How I can controll/set the encoding used by jar built with shade plugin?
3. How I can force PDF box to return text in correct format?

I know that in command line PDFBox there is option to set encoding:

```
java -jar {$jar_path} ExtractText -encoding UTF-8
```

But I can't find it in PdfBox api...

---

Solved: I had to change

```
pdfStripper.getText(this.document).getBytes();
```

to

```
pdfStripper.getText(this.document).getBytes("UTF8");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here is 2 facts (about your question 2):

- According [this code](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/apache/pdfbox/ExtractText.java.html) : the default output encoding is UTF-8.
- There is a [PDFTextStripper constructor](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper.html#PDFTextStripper%28java.lang.String%29) taking the output encoding as an argument.

For question 1 and 3:

I think your problem is more related to the way you transform the `byte[]` returned by `extractText()` into a String.

`new String(byte[])` use the platform encoding. So, doing this within netbeans or in shell can give different results since I expect that the platform encoding can be different when running within Netbeans.

Posting the code handling the result of your `extractText()` can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, you were right about string - In above code I use `pdfStripper.getText(this.document).getBytes();` which is `String.getBytes()` - I had to change this line to `pdfStripper.getText(this.document).getBytes("UTF8");` and it solved problem, thanks!